# Trying to find overlapping entries

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am relatively new to ArcGIS and I had a question. I am working with a data set relating to cities and towns.

I am trying to find cities that have the same name as towns. Currently, the syntax I am using is such: "CSD_NAME" LIKE "NAME". But this is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Can we assume each record in your data set has two fields, "CSD_NAME" and "NAME"? If so perhaps try the Arc equivalent to the expression in Qgis "CSD_NAME" ILIKE "NAME" in case there are case differences [I don't know the Arc syntax but perhaps UPPER(CSD_NAME) = UPPER(NAME)]. Or are you trying to match two separate entries on the basis of identical spatial location?